# Getting rates from an array - json

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I am trying to get the rates from this [website](https://bitpay.com/api/rates).

So I connect with `website = Faraday.get('https://bitpay.com/api/rates')).status == 200` and then try to parse this.

A segment of the response I get is:

```
 #<Faraday::Response:0x007fcf1ce25688
  @env=
  #<struct Faraday::Env
  method=:get,
  body=
  "[{\"code\":\"BTC\",\"name\":\"Bitcoin\",\"rate\":1},      {\"code\":\"USD\",\"name\":\"US Dollar\",\"rate\":586.66},{\"code\":\"EUR\",\"name\":\"Eurozone Euro\",\"rate\":528.991322},{\"code\":\"GBP\",\"name\":\"Pound Sterling\",\"rate\":449.441986},{\"code\":\"JPY\",\"name\":\"Japanese Yen\",\"rate\":59907.95922},{\"code\":\"CAD\",\"name\"
```

When I do a website.body I get a String class of all these values found on that website. I want to parse them though (JSON?) so that I can get each rate as a float.

I tried something `JSON.parse(website.body)["GBP"]["rate"].to_f` but yet again it cannot work in a string.

The return I get is `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

I was having a similar (but not the same) format from a different rates website and this is how I was handling it. Do I need to change its format first or is there a different way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access to the parsed JSON with the key `"GBP"` but you have an array. It's like if you did

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a['foo']
```

Try out

```
currencies = JSON.parse(website.body)
currencies.each { |currency| puts currency['rate'] }
```

and change it like you need